# values are not being inserted into database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$lat=$_GET["latitudee"];
$lon=$_GET["longitude"];
$sql="INSERT INTO coordinates(latitude,longitude)
      VALUES ('$_POST[$lat]','$_POST[$lon]')";
       if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
      echo "1 record added";
  ?>
```

This is the table i have in my database :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coordinates` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latitude` float NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

> http://localhost.com/input.php?latitudee=3.14159&longitude=4.14159

values are not being inserted. what is the problem?

Comment: Don't know.  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no error... it says "1 record added" but values are not there

Comment: Why you using `$_POST` when you are using a `GET` method ?

Comment: you didnt commit the transaction? did you see the message, 1 record added?

Comment: yes.it gives message "1 record added"

Comment: Ok, so probably, even if the parametrs where wrong, atleaste mtpy data should have been inserted! if transaction is commited.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO coordinates(latitude,longitude)
VALUES
('$lat','$lon')";
```

bacause you stored get value in variable like this  :

```
$lat=$_GET["latitudee"];
$lon=$_GET["longitude"];
```

and in your query you write this:
   `$_POST[$lat]','$_POST[$lon]` so change it like i suggest.

**Side note:** make sure what method you used: `POST or GET` and `escape` the variable to prevent sql injection.

[Read this:How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: The data you try to insert is passed through the URL. Therefor, they are in the $_GET array. The $_POST array is typically used when using a form to POST data. By defining $lat and $lon you have the information from the URL in these two vars and you can use the info in your query. Note that your code is subject to SQL injection..

Comment: Did you give him an example that is free of SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$lat=$_GET["latitudee"];
$lon=$_GET["longitude"];
$sql="INSERT INTO coordinates(latitude,longitude)
      VALUES ('$lat','$lon')";
$In_qrr = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       if (!In_qrr)
        {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
      echo "1 record added";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo error in $_GET["**latitudee**"] index. Need **latitude** instead **latitudee**
2. Your code works fine. Maybe $_GET and $_POST elements are not set. Enable error_reporting or use this checking code.

```

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

//--
echo isset($_GET["latitudee"]) ?: 'GET array element with index latitudee is not set';
echo isset($_GET["longitude"]) ?: 'GET array element with index longitude is not set';
//--

$lat=$_GET["latitudee"];
$lon=$_GET["longitude"];

//--
echo isset($_POST[$lat]) ?: 'POST array element with index ' . $lat . ' is not set';
echo isset($_POST[$lon]) ?: 'POST array element with index ' . $lon . ' is not set';
//--

$sql="INSERT INTO coordinates(latitude,longitude)
VALUES
    ('$_POST[$lat]','$_POST[$lon]')";
       if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
      echo "1 record added";
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to use $lat at the place of $_POST[$lat].since you have already assign $lat=$_GET["latitudee"]; so why are you using $_POST[$lat].please use below code.

```
 <?php
    include 'config.php';
    $lat=$_GET["latitudee"];
    $lon=$_GET["longitude"];
    $sql="INSERT INTO coordinates(latitude,longitude)
          VALUES ('$lat','$lon')";
           if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
           die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
          echo "1 record added";
      ?>
```